# Warning: urlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in and not getting the preffered output

Tags: query-posts, errors

> Warning:  urlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in `D:\xamppp\htdocs\sample\wp-includes\formatting.php` on line 3690

When I try to give the `category_name` in  the `query_post`,

```
<?php
   $args=query_posts(
    array(
     'posts_per_page' => -1,
   'category_name' =>array('Breaking News Stories', 'Call-out', 'Featured Story', 'Standard Stories')
  ));
 ?>
```

I'm having the above warning in `formatting.php` file.
line 3690 has the below code:

```
<?php
   function wp_basename( $path, $suffix = '' )
     {
      return urldecode( basename( str_replace( array( '%2F', '%5C' ), '/', urlencode( $path ) ), $suffix ) );
     }
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, never use [`query_posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/). Rather use [`WP_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) to construct your custom query which is the prefered way

You are also using the `category_name` parameter wrong. If you look at the `WP_Query` documentation, it states

> **category_name (string)** - use category slug (NOT name).

Go and have a look at the examples given in the docomentation under the category parameters

**EDIT**

You need to do someting like this

```
'category_name' => 'SLUG OF Breaking News Stories, SLUG OF Call-out, SLUG OF Featured Story, SLUG OF Standard Stories'
```

Answer (score 3):

Very helpful response by Pieter Goosen.
Had a similar issue that was fixed by imploding our array.

`'category_name' => $my_array ? implode( ',', $my_array ) : '',`

ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Answer (score 1):

- This means the variable `$path` is an array().
- You have to pull only the path (a string value) from it.
- You can do `print_r($path)` to see what values it contains.

e.g. if it shows something like this `Array([0] => path/to/file)` , you will need to use `urlencode($path[0])` instead of `urlencode($path)`.

Comment: That piece of code is a core function. The incorrect use of `category_name` is triggering the error. The error is "incorrectly" refered to that specific file the OP has stated